# How to distinguish unassigned variable from zero in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, unassigned-variable

Some external code runs my function of the following code:

```
def __init__(self,weights=None,threshold=None):

    print "weights: ", weights
    print "threshold: ", threshold

    if weights:
        print "weights assigned"
        self.weights = weights
    if threshold:
        print "threshold assigned"
        self.threshold = threshold
```

And this code outputs:

```
weights:  [1, 2]
threshold:  0
weights assigned
```

I.e. print operator behaves like `threshold` is zero, while `if` operator behaves like it was not defined.

What is the correct interpretation? What is happening? What is the state of `threshold` parameter and how to recognize it?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. `0` is false in a boolean context in Python.

Comment: So, they are passing zero for `threshold`. And what is assigned to `self.threshold` in result?

Comment: There is not such thing as an undefined variable in Python. I am guessing you mean `threshold=None` means undefined, but it means `threshold` is default assigned `None` if no argument is given. Both `None` and `0` are considered `False`.

Comment: Nothing, beccause `if threshold` does not evaluate to true.

Comment: @DanielRoseman and what is "nothing"? The same as `None` or not?

Comment: No. It is not defined at all. Because the code never enters the block where it is defined.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Is it possible to make that nothing for omitted parameters?

Comment: Sure; don't bother with the `if`, and always define it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman. no I mean how to define optional parameter for a function, which appears in the state of "nothing" if not passed?

Comment: You've done that already.

Answer (score 6):

Use `if weights is not None` instead of `if weights`.

More detail: when you say `if weights` you're asking Python to evaluate `weights` in a boolean context, and many things can be "false-equivalent" (or "falsy") including `0`, empty strings, empty containers, etc. If you want to only check for a `None` value, you have to do that explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly test for a `None` value.

```
def __init__(self,weights=None,threshold=None):
    print "weights: ", weights
    print "threshold: ", threshold

    if weights is not None:
        print "weights assigned"
        self.weights = weights
    if threshold is not None:
        print "threshold assigned"
        self.threshold = threshold
```

Comment: `if not weights == None:` isn't it the same as `if weights != None`? Also, you can test for the `type()` too, though that's not very pythonic.

Comment: You should generally use identity comparison against `None`, not equality. (i.e. `is None` or `is not None` instead of `==` and `!=`.

Comment: You are correct. I fixed the answer. Thx!